# Not able to load Css, Js files in swagger-ui.html page when running behind Ngnix server in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, nginx, swagger, swagger-ui, nginx-reverse-proxy

Swagger UI loads well on local. But the CSS,JS files don't load when running behind the Nginx server.
I tried with the static files for the Nginx server. Also tried with changing the context route.
Url:- `https://domain-name/static/workflow-service-java/swagger-ui`

```
 location /workflow-service-java/swagger-ui {
    proxy_pass http://workflow-service-java:8080/swagger-ui;
  }
```

And here is the Java code.

This is the config for swagger

```
   @Configuration
    @EnableSwagger2WebMvc
        public class SwaggerConfig  implements WebMvcConfigurer{
        
            
        
            
        
            public static final String AUTHORIZATION_HEADER = "Authorization";
            @Bean
            public Docket postApi(HttpServletRequest request) {
                return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).securityContexts(Lists.newArrayList(securityContext())).apiInfo(apiInfo())
                        .securitySchemes(Lists.newArrayList(apiKey()))
                        .select()
                        .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.accion.workflow.controller")).paths(PathSelectors.any())
                        .build();
            }
        
            private ApiKey apiKey() {
                 return new ApiKey("Bearer", AUTHORIZATION_HEADER, "header");
            }
        
            private SecurityContext securityContext() {
                 return SecurityContext.builder()
                            .securityReferences(defaultAuth())
                            .forPaths(PathSelectors.any())
                            .build();
            }
        
             List<SecurityReference> defaultAuth() {
                 
                AuthorizationScope authorizationScope
                    = new AuthorizationScope("global", "accessEverything");
                AuthorizationScope[] authorizationScopes = new AuthorizationScope[1];
                authorizationScopes[0] = authorizationScope;
                return Lists.newArrayList(
                    new SecurityReference("Bearer", authorizationScopes));
            }
        
            private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
                return new ApiInfoBuilder().title(WorkflowConstants.WorflowServiceConstants.TITLE)
                        .description(WorkflowConstants.WorflowServiceConstants.DESCRIPTION)
                        .termsOfServiceUrl(WorkflowConstants.WorflowServiceConstants.TERMSOFSERVICEURL)
                        .licenseUrl(WorkflowConstants.WorflowServiceConstants.LICENCSEURL).version(WorkflowConstants.WorflowServiceConstants.VERSION).build();
            }
            
        }
```

[image]

you can see the request url is appended with "/" character
Please help!!. How do we handle this in Nginx

Here is the default.conf file

```
server {
 
  listen       80;
  server_name  localhost;

  access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main; 
 
  charset UTF-8;

  sendfile on;
  tcp_nopush on;
  tcp_nodelay on;
  keepalive_timeout 65;
  types_hash_max_size 2048;
  server_tokens off;

  include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type application/octet-stream;

  #server_names_hash_bucket_size 128;
  client_max_body_size 7M;
  max_ranges 8;

  gzip on;
  gzip_http_version 1.1;
  gzip_disable      "MSIE [1-6]\.";
  gzip_min_length   256;
  gzip_vary         on;
  gzip_comp_level 6;
  gzip_buffers 16 8k;
  gzip_proxied      any;
  gzip_types        text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

  root /usr/share/nginx/html;
  index index.html index.htm;


 
  location /workflow-service-java/swagger-ui {
    proxy_pass http://workflow-service-java:8080/swagger-ui;
  }
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how your assets URIs actually looking (are they absolute or relative), but with this configuration:

```
location /workflow-service-java/api-docs/ {
    proxy_pass http://workflow-service-java:8080/api-docs/swagger-ui.html;
}
```

your request to `/workflow-service-java/api-docs/some/file` would be passed to your backend as `/api-docs/swagger-ui.htmlsome/file`, which is obviously not what you want. Usually you should use `try_files` to serve static assets from nginx itself and pass a request to your backend for dynamic content only. For example, assuming your assets located in `/some/path/api-docs` folder:

```
location /workflow-service-java/api-docs/ {
    alias /some/path/api-docs/;
    try_files $uri @swagger;
}
location @swagger {
    # remove "/workflow-service-java" from the URI that would be passed to backend
    rewrite ^/workflow-service-java(/.*)$ $1 break;
    proxy_pass http://workflow-service-java:8080;
}
```

Comment: So here `/workflow-service-java` is the service pod name in kubernates. And now the Api endpoint is `/swagger-ui/`. Here I'm using the latest plugin snapshot of swagger

Comment: @TanmayNaik Can you include your full `server` block from nginx config? You can omit private info like the domain name, certificates path etc.

Comment: See i have added the default.conf file

Comment: We tried with strip path also, but the ```swagger-resources``` has inherited calling in them. We have a Kubernetes pod which has service name ```workflow-service-java```

Comment: @TanmayNaik Sorry, I think I can't help you further. It has something to do with swagger itself, and only someone who has both swagger and nginx knowledge could help you. Isn't [this](https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/issues/1717) issue is about your situation?

Comment: it is related to this [issue](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/1330)